# What is the URI for files in my Documents folder?

Tags: android, filesystems

I want to use this to access a file xxx.txt in my Documents folder. How would I reference the file?

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("/Internal storage/New Folder/Documents/xxx.txt")))
```

I also tried "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/" but had the same result.

This results in File Not Found.

Comment: A file in folder is no asset. So do without Asset. And how did you create New Folder? Pretty unclear where you have that txt file exactly.

Comment: `using` Is that Java? Which ide?

Comment: The text file is in my Documents folder, in Internal Storage. At least this is how it appears on the phone.

Comment: The code is C#/Xamarin.